# PHP Code to send html email with attachment to Iphone Mail

Tags: php, html, iphone, email

I have a website contact form that sends HTML email with photo attachments as an email to Iphone mail application. I am receiving the following error message on my Iphone:

"**This message cannot be displayed because of the way it is formatted. Ask the sender to send it again using a different format or email program. multipart/mixed"**.

Is this has something to do with email content-type and how to fix it in my PHP code.

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n";
$headers .= "From:".$from_email."\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$sender_email."" . "\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n";
$body = "--$boundary\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$body .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";
$body .= chunk_split(base64_encode($message_body));
$sentMail = mail($recipient_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
```

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35635777/error-with-attaching-large-pdf-to-mail-composer-ios-9-2-1 It could be related to the size of attachment

Comment: I'd suggest using one of the various mail libraries available for PHP e.g. SwiftMailer, PHPMailer rather than doing this by hand.

Comment: @TDK usually it is attaching small JPEG photos, any other solution?

Comment: @JonStirling i am not familiar with the examples you gave? anyway to explain further please

Comment: Google is a great tool for looking up libraries.

Comment: @JonStirling the problem is only appearing with Iphone. the email works fine with android and web based email

Comment: @JonStirling I am hoping to find a fix for Iphone instead of having to try another approach

Comment: If it's an issue specifically with iOS software, then I have no idea. There appear to be quite a number of these errors over the years for that app.